# JavaScript draw database schema

Tags: javascript, database, raphael

I have the need to display a couple of database tables' structure (4-5 tops) in a HTML page. I have to show the columns, mark the primary key and also draw the foreign keys connections (arrows I guess).

I have chosen raphael.js and it's all fine except for the foreign keys arrows, because they have to avoid intersection with tables and do it in a fancy way e.g. turning around corners and stuff.

Does anybody know of a solution to that? If not, how can I easily draw the arrows?

What I have for now as a try-out is http://jsfiddle.net/eKF6R/

And it's fine for connecting the tables but I need to connect the specific columns and also to avoid intersection.

Comment: doesn't really answer your questions, but maybe you're intrested in this http://ondras.zarovi.cz/sql/demo/

Comment: I think you can take a look at MindMaps visualization software... it is basically the same visualization that you need here. Take this for instance: http://code.google.com/p/js-mindmap/

Comment: Yep, that crossed my mind. Shall try this too. Meanwhile, I think I have a working solution for now, shall post it here in the comments tomorrow so that somebody my stuble upon it someday.

Comment: looks like phpmyadmin's "designer" view: http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2011/phpmyadmin-designer-view

Answer (score 4):

Try this site http://dbdsgnr.appspot.com/
Hope it help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the following doc reference from Raphaël:
http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.path

You can use 'L' as parameter to draw lines instead curves:

```
var path = ["M", x1.toFixed(3), y1.toFixed(3), "L", x2, y2, x3, y3, x4.toFixed(3), y4.toFixed(3)].join(",");
```

Maybe it's been 2 years from your question, but many people could have the same question (as I was).

Best Regards.